# Surprising behavior of Java 8 CompletableFuture exceptionally method

Tags: exception, java-8, completable-future

I have encountered strange behavior of Java 8 CompletableFuture.exceptionally method. If I execute this code, it works fine and prints `java.lang.RuntimeException`

```
CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

future.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException());

future.exceptionally(e -> {
            System.out.println(e.getClass());
            return null;
});
```

But if I add another step in the future processing like `thenApply`, the exception type changes to `java.util.concurrent.CompletionException` with the original exception wrapped inside.

```
CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

future.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException());

future.thenApply(v-> v).exceptionally(e -> {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
});
```

Is there any reason why this should be happening? In my opinion, it's quite surprising.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49230980/14731 for an overview of when the exception is wrapped (or not).

Comment: Here's an article that I found that helped me understand the solutions to this problem, better -> http://millross-consultants.com/completable-future-error-propagation.html

Comment: @The0bserver, The link you have added is quite informative and clear lots of my doubt though not all :)

Comment: Glad I could be of some help @NIGAGA .

Comment: For anyone interested [here is an archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20190929235406/http://millross-consultants.com/completable-future-error-propagation.html) of the above-mentioned article.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This behavior [is specified in the class documentation of `CompletionStage` (fourth bullet)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html):

> Method [`handle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) additionally allows the stage to compute a replacement result that may enable further processing by other dependent stages. In all other cases, if a stage's computation terminates abruptly with an (unchecked) exception or error, then all dependent stages requiring its completion complete exceptionally as well, with a [`CompletionException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionException.html) holding the exception as its cause.

It’s not that surprising if you consider that you may *want* to know whether the stage you have invoked `exceptionally` on failed, or one of its direct or indirect prerequisites.

Answer (score 6):

yes, the behavior is expected, but if you want the original exception which was thrown from one of the previous stages, you can simply use this

```
CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

future.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException());

future.thenApply(v-> v).exceptionally(e -> {
        System.out.println(e.getCause()); // returns a throwable back
        return null;
});
```