# Functional Java - Interaction between whenComplete and exceptionally

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

In this code:

```
doSomethingThatMightThrowAnException()
  .whenComplete((result, ex) -> doSomethingElse()})
  .exceptionally(ex -> handleException(ex));
```

When there is an exception from `doSomethingThatMightThrowAnException`, are both `doSomethingElse` and `handleException` run, or is the exception consumed by either the `whenComplete` or the `exceptionally`?

**EDIT:**

`doSomethingThatMightThrowAnException` returns a `CompletableFuture`, which might `completeExceptionally`. This is the exception I'm talking about.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [documentation of `whenComplete`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) says:

> Returns a new CompletionStage **with the same result or exception as this stage**, that executes the given action when this stage completes.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

This implies that an exception is not swallowed by this stage as it is supposed to have the same result or exception. However, you might be surprised by the fact that subsequent stages will receive the exception of a previous stage wrapped within a `CompletionException`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430255/surprising-behavior-of-java-8-completablefuture-exceptionally-method), so it’s not exactly the same exception:

```
CompletableFuture<String> test=new CompletableFuture<>();
test.whenComplete((result, ex) -> System.out.println("stage 2: "+result+"\t"+ex))
    .exceptionally(ex -> { System.out.println("stage 3: "+ex); return ""; });
test.completeExceptionally(new IOException());
```

will print:

```
stage 2: null   java.io.IOException
stage 3: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.io.IOException
```

Note that you can always append multiple actions on one stage instead of chaining then:

```
CompletableFuture<String> test=new CompletableFuture<>();
test.whenComplete((result, ex) -> System.out.println("stage 2a: "+result+"\t"+ex));
test.exceptionally(ex -> { System.out.println("stage 2b: "+ex); return ""; });
test.completeExceptionally(new IOException());
```

```
stage 2b: java.io.IOException
stage 2a: null  java.io.IOException
```

Of course, since now there is no dependency between the stage `2a` and `2b`, there is no ordering between them and in the case of async action, they may run concurrently.

Answer (score 4):

The [exceptionally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-) method states:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when this CompletableFuture completes, with the result of the given function of the exception triggering this CompletableFuture's completion when it completes exceptionally; otherwise, if this CompletableFuture completes normally, then the returned CompletableFuture also completes normally with the same value. Note: More flexible versions of this functionality are available using methods whenComplete and handle.

This is not, IMHO written in the clearest english but I would say that means that if an exception is thrown then only the `exceptionally` action will be triggered. If no exception is thrown then only the `normal` action will be performed.

Answer (score 0):

`doSomethingThatMightThrowAnException()` is chained with `.whenComplete((result, ex) -> doSomethingElse()})` and `.exceptionally(ex -> handleException(ex));` but if it throws an exception it ends right there as no object will be passed on in the chain.

Remember that an exception will throw out to the caller, so unless `doSomethingThatMightThrowAnException()` catches the exception internally it will throw out. If this is your class you should know if it does throw, if not check docs for libraries that you use.