# Does CompletionStage always wrap exceptions in CompletionException?

Tags: java, completable-future

The [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) Javadoc states:

> [...] if a stage's computation terminates abruptly with an (unchecked) exception or error, then all dependent stages requiring its completion complete exceptionally as well, with a CompletionException holding the exception as its cause.

Seeing as exceptional completions always wrap exceptions in `CompletionException` why do `exceptionally()`, `whenComplete()` and `handle()` represent the exception as `Throwable` instead of `CompletionException`?

This matters because it prevents one from directly re-throwing exceptions inside these methods.

**Is it possible for these methods to receive an exception other than `CompletionException`? Or can I safely force a cast to this type?**

(I ran some tests locally, as well as dig through the CompletableFuture source-code and, at first glance, I do not see how any other type of exception could be thrown.)

Comment: Interesting question.  I would write up a quick [mcve] to see what it actually does... but it's WAY past my bedtime :-)

Comment: @JimGarrison I ran some tests locally, as well as dig through the `CompletableFuture` code and at first glance I do not see how any other type of exception could be thrown. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: good question :) never thought about it this way

Comment: Register a `whenComplete` with a raw `CompletableFuture`, then `completeExceptionally` passing a checked exception.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you please post an answer with a code sample?

Comment: [Here's](https://ideone.com/AAsuf9) what I mean. I tried to write an answer but there's always something in the documentation that blocks a full explanation. The gist of it was that the quote you posted refers to the `Function`, `Consumer`, or `Runnable` used in a continuation throwing an exception, not to an exception used to complete a `CompletionStage`. Note that the interface _does not define methods for initially creating, forcibly completing normally or exceptionally [...]_. Those use cases are deferred to implementations.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are right. Now that I know what to look for in the source-code, I see two methods that can throw arbitrary exceptions: `completeExceptionally()` and `obtrudeException()`. Post an answer with these details and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is it possible for these methods to receive an exception other than
>   `CompletionException`?

Yes, it is possible and you shouldn't cast to `CompletionException` without an `instanceof` check (or a review of your usage).

Take this example

```
CompletableFuture<Void> root = new CompletableFuture<>();
root.whenComplete((v, t) -> {
    System.out.println(t.getClass()); // class java.io.IOException
});
root.completeExceptionally(new IOException("blow it up"));
```

`whenComplete` will receive the `IOException` rather than a `CompletionException` wrapping it. The same behavior applies to `exceptionally` and `handle`.

---

A stage's computation is defined in the Javadoc:

> The computation performed by a stage may be expressed as a `Function`,
>   `Consumer`, or `Runnable` (using methods with names including apply,
>   accept, or run, respectively) depending on whether it requires
>   arguments and/or produces results.

I believe this quote

> if a stage's computation terminates abruptly with an (unchecked)
>   exception or error

is referring to one of those `Function#apply`, `Consumer#accept`, or `Runnable#run` methods terminating abruptly because of a [thrown exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18), not because a stage completed exceptionally through some other mechanism.

Note also that the Javadoc says

> This interface does not define methods for initially creating,
>   forcibly completing normally or **exceptionally**, probing completion
>   status or results, or awaiting completion of a stage. Implementations
>   of `CompletionStage` may provide means of achieving such effects, as
>   appropriate

In other words, the interface allows implementations to complete stages exceptionally without abruptly terminating any computation. I think this allows for new behavior.

---

If we extend my example from before

```
CompletableFuture<Void> root = new CompletableFuture<>();
CompletableFuture<Void> child = root.whenComplete((v, t) -> {
    System.out.println(t.getClass()); // class java.io.Exception
});
child.whenComplete((v, t) -> {
    System.out.println(t.getClass()); // class java.util.concurrent.CompletionException
});
root.completeExceptionally(new IOException("blow it up"));
```

You'll notice the completion attached to the `child` receives a `CompletionException` wrapping the original `IOException`. This isn't obvious to me from the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-), which states

> Returns a new `CompletionStage` with the **same** result or **exception** as
>   this stage

All in all, it seems like the raw exception from a `completeExceptionally` is passed down to direct dependents, while dependents of dependents receive an enclosing `CompletionException`.

Comment: According to discussion on Java bug JDK-8233050, this is as (confusingly) documented - the second `whenComplete()` treats the previous step's propagation of an exception as the abrupt termination of a computation stage. Apparently I'm not the only one to disagree with this as there also exist bugs JDK-8172177, JDK-8199501 and JDK-8068432 (possibly more, but you get the gist), all unresolved and unattended.

Comment: In fact, in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html its said "if a stage's computation terminates abruptly with an (unchecked) exception or error, then all dependent stages requiring its completion complete exceptionally as well, with a CompletionException holding the exception as its cause".