# How to debug CompletableStage deadlocks?

Tags: java, debugging, asynchronous, completable-future

The most difficult debugging problem I've run across recently is deadlocks between asynchronous operations. For example, given two `CompletionStage` chains, where the first chain invokes a method that depends upon the completion of the second chain, and the second chain invokes a method that depends upon the completion of the first chain. It isn't this obvious in real-life because the dependency tends to be hidden and sometimes deadlocks involve more than three parties.

Part of the problem is that there is no way to find out what a `CompletableStage` is waiting on. This is because an operation references a `CompletableStage`, not the other way around.

Most debuggers provide some level of deadlock detection nowadays, but this only applies to threads. **How does one debug deadlocks between CompletableStage chains?**

Comment: Could you give an example where this situation happens? I think there are 2 possible situations but I might miss some: when you manually manage a `CompletableFuture` with `new`/`complete()`, and when one of the tasks in the chain calls `get()`/`join()` on a descendant stage. The first case seems quite difficult to detect (probably requires code analysis) and the second one seems a bit contrived. Is it something often happening in real life? It seems it would be more likely to have deadlocks involving other mechanisms (`synchronized`, database transactions etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

- At the end of each `CompletionStage` chain, schedule an event that will get fired after a timeout:

  ```
  Set<Object> knownDeadlocks = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
  // ...
  Future<?> deadlockListener = scope.getScheduler().schedule(() ->
  {
      if (knownDeadlocks.add(Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(context)))
          log.warn("Possible deadlock", context);
  }, DEADLOCK_DURATION.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  ```
- Use `CompletionStage.handle()` to disable deadlockListener if the stage completes as expected:

  ```
  return stage.handle((value, throwable) ->
  {
      // WARNING: By design, CompletionStage.whenComplete() suppresses any exceptions thrown by its argument, so we use handle() instead.
      deadlockListener.cancel(false);
      if (throwable == null)
          return value;
      return rethrowException(throwable);
  });
  ```
- For completeness, you also have:

  ```
  /**
   * Rethrows a {@code Throwable}, wrapping it in {@code CompletionException} if it isn't already wrapped.
   *
   * @param <T>       the return type expected by the caller
   * @param throwable a Throwable
   * @return an undefined value (the method always throws an exception)
   * @throws CompletionException wraps {@code throwable}
   */
  public <T> T rethrowException(Throwable throwable)
  {
      if (throwable instanceof CompletionException)
          throw (CompletionException) throwable;
      if (throwable == null)
          throwable = new NullPointerException("throwable may not be null");
      // According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49261367/14731 some methods do not wrap exceptions
      throw new CompletionException(throwable);
  }
  ```