# CompletableFuture and exceptionally - what is missing here?

Tags: java, exception, java-8, completable-future

As I try to understand the `exceptionally` functionality, I read several [blogs](https://dzone.com/articles/20-examples-of-using-javas-completablefuture) and [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430255/surprising-behavior-of-java-8-completablefuture-exceptionally-method) , but I don't understand what is wrong with this code:

```
 public CompletableFuture<String> divideByZero(){
    int x = 5 / 0;
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("hi there");
}
```

I thought that I will be able to catch the exception when calling the `divideByZero` method with the `exceptionally` or the `handle`, but the program simply prints the stack trace and exits.

I tried both or `handle` & `exceptionally`:

```
            divideByZero()
            .thenAccept(x -> System.out.println(x))
            .handle((result, ex) -> {
                if (null != ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return "excepion";
                } else {
                    System.out.println("OK");
                    return result;
                }

            })
```

But the result is always:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Comment: your this block must be inside try catch if it may throw an exception
 public CompletableFuture<String> divideByZero(){
    int x = 5 / 0;
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("hi there");
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `divideByZero()`, the code `int x = 5 / 0;` runs immediately in the caller's thread, which explains why it's failing as you describe (the exception is being raised even before a `CompletableFuture` object gets created).

If you want the division by zero to be run in the future's task, you may need to change the method to something like this:

```
public static CompletableFuture<String> divideByZero() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        int x = 5 / 0;
        return "hi there";
    });
}
```

Which ends with `Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero` (caused by `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`)